# Allow Windows Powershell through Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-7, powershell, windows-firewall

Running Windows 7 Ultimate x64

I am running Windows Firewall in an include only fashion (only programs I explicitly allow can access the internet).

I'm having trouble getting Powershell the ability to access the internet.

**UPDATE: Example of What I am doing:**

```
$wc = new-object system.net.webclient;
$wc.DownloadString("http://www.superuser.com") > html.txt
```

I've allowed the executable at both SysWow64 and in Windows\System32 with no such luck. Is there a service I need to allow?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? If PowerShell is triggering other programs (even seemingly innocuous ones) I think it is *those* programs, and not PowerShell, that will need firewall permissions.

Comment: See the Update to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell.exe is the process doing the work (that is, your code here doesn't spawn any child processes) so I'm not sure what your problem might be.  I'm also assuming if you disable the firewall you have no problems at all.

I would get [SysInternals' ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and use it to monitor Powershell.exe when you execute the second line of code in your example there.  Look for whatever operation is getting an access denied error.  That should give you a clue about what's going on.

I would also try using `$downloadString = $wc.DownloadString("http://www.superuser.com")` just so you can eliminate any possibility that your output file is where the problem is.